# I can't write anything to second partition. Only root partition appears on file system

Tags: partitioning

**Thanks for all suggestions. I have reinstalled ubuntu and put a single partition for all disk. I hope answers under this question helps someone else in future. For me, it was hard to understand as a newby Ubuntu user :) Thanks again.**

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my new internal SSD 240 GB.

I have created partitions manually when I start installation as:

swap 512MB,

root 40 GB ext4,

EFI 1 GB,

Other (around) 190 GB fat32.

When installation has enden I didn't see my "other" partition on file browser. Somehow it seen when I open Disks app or Gparted app.
I thought that it has happened because I partitioned as fat32. So I have deleted that partition by using Gparted and I create a new partition with same size as ext4.
After `sudo parted -l`, I get:

[image: After sudo parted -l, I get:]

So the problem part is number 4

How can I see and write on my 198 GB partition?
TIA

Comment: If this is not dual boot why the fat32 part? How much memory do you have? The swap size does not make sense. generally, swap should be half the size of the physical memory. 2GB is enough size for the swap if the RAM is 4GB.

Comment: Hi. I did it fat32 that if someday I need to install Windows for some reason, I can do it there. But now I think It is ok to go with single operating system. I have 8 GB RAM. Is there a way to expand swap area? And what about my first question?

Comment: One thing at a time. If I were you I would be redoing the install from scratch with no fat32 and a 4 gig swap partition. If after that there is an access issue it can be addressed.

Comment: Should I do it like 4gb swap, 40 gb ext4, 1 gb EFI and rest ext4? Or do I even need EFI? All tutorials on web says "create an EFI partiton". And should I do both partitons as primary or big partiton should be logical?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. This way if you do want to install Windows or any other OS in the future you can just slice off a bit of the last part. Maybe make that 40 gig one, the sec part 60 gig so home has room to grow.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell the OS where to mount that partition; check `/etc/fstab` to see if there is an entry for it. If there isn't then create a mount point for it on the root filesystem, check that you can mount it with the mount command and when it works and add an entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount it automatically at boot.  The man pages for the `mount` command and the format of `/etc/fstab` will help you. See also [the Ubuntu help wiki page on fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Comment: I have a look in fstab file. But I can't say that I understand too much. So i think i will go with a new installation. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You just need to follow the format that fstab requires. And change an example to your UUID & mount point. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700

Answer (score 0):

> So I have deleted that partition by using Gparted and I create a new partition with same size as ext4.

GParted always runs as root therefore the partition you created is owned by root.

You can either `chown user:user mountpoint -R` (please note that "user" and "mountpoint" are placeholders and "-R" means recursive) or, considering that you have nothing there, simply use Disks instead of Gparted. Disks runs as your own user therefore the partitions it creates are owned by you. Simply select, remove and create another with the right-click menu.